# Radar Charts on Scene Builder

Tags: java, charts, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am asking if there is a possibility to design radar charts (like in picture attached) directly in Scene Builder for a JavaFX application ? Or is it more practical to work with iReport or Jaspersoft (if it is compatible with a JavaFX application). If there is another solution more professional, your advices are welcome.

I am doing an desktop application who design somes charts after calculating employees performance. The application is for a bank.

Picture :

[Radar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEyoX.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SceneBuilder is primarily a WYSIWYG tool for UI design – if I understood correctly, you do not have the radar charts ready, but need to design the control itself? Right?

When I design controls, I code the control and put it in a minimal hello world environment or UI test case, in order to see most quickly if it works and looks as intended.

SceneBuilder is only used when the control is ready and packaged. With the "JAR/FXML Manager" of SceneBuilder you can import you control into the Library and place it into your UI.

Does this information help you?

Comment: Yes, it makes sence, I will try to use JAR/FXML and see what it will go. Thank you so much